# Fill specific row in a 2D array Java

Tags: java, arrays

i was wondering if we can in java fill a specified case in a 2D array 
for example

```
String[][] Dictionary = new String[25][2];
Dictionary[count][] = word.getName();
Dictionary[][count] = word.getHint();
```

i don't know if am being clear in my question but all what i am searching for is to fill part by part the 2D array not all the row or all the columns

Comment: You just can't fill A DIMENSION in array like that. you need to provide the specific index to fill an array. ( If I understood your question right).

Comment: What does `word.getName()` return?  A 2D array is 1-D array of references to 1-D arrays.

Comment: return string , and all i want is to fill the name of the word then fill its hint next to it

Answer (score 1):

not shure what you are trying, but if you want to fill in whole columns or rows you could do that the following way:

```
int size=100;
int dest=50; //value of the column/row you want to fill
String[][] Dictionary = new String[size][size];
//LOOP FOR FILLING COLUMN  :
for (int i=0; i< size;i++){
Dictionary[i][dest] = word.getName();
}
//LOOP FOR FILLING ROW :
for (int i=0; i< size;i++){
Dictionary[dest][i] = word.getName();
}
```

IF you just want to puncutal enter a specific value at a specific index in your array you must fill in your prevered indices in the "breaks":

```
i=1; //index row
j==1;//index column
Dictionary[i][j] = word.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a 2D array in Java. Java only has arrays of arrays. So your 2D array is in fact an array of rows. A row being itself an array of Strings. So if you want to replace the third "row" of your array, you would use

```
dictionary[2] = new String[] {"hello", "world"};
```

If you want to fill the existing cells of the third row, you would use

```
dictionary[2][0] = "hello";
dictionary[2][1] = "world";
```

If you want to fill the second "column" of your array, you would use

```
dictionary[0][1] = "hello";
dictionary[1][1] = "world";
dictionary[2][1] = "!";
...
```

Comment: What else is a 2d array if not an array of arrays? Other languages may give you a special syntax to work with them but surely it's the same thing?

Comment: Pascal, for example, has real multi-dimensional arrays (http://pascal-programming.info/lesson10.php). They're symmetrical, unlike Java (which allows replacing a row, but not a column), and they can't have, unlike Java, a row that doesn't have the same number of elements than the other ones. They can't have a null row, unlike Java. They're thus real 2D arrays.

Comment: I still think its a bit misleading to state that "there is no such thing as a 2D array in Java". An array of arrays is generally known as a 2D array in any language. Pascal gives you a bit extra but it's still a 2D array. 
TBH it's by the bye as multi-dimensional arrays are a bit of a rarity anyway. That tutorial even says so itself. Java is OO and there's usually a better OO solution than using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to do something like this.

```
String[][] dictionary = new String[25][2];
Dictionary[count][0] = word.getName();
Dictionary[count][1] = word.getHint();
```

Depending on what you're trying to do you might be better off doing this a little differently. For instance if you're storing a collection of names for which you want to lookup a hint then you might want to look at using a map.

```
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
dictionary.put(word.getName(), word.getHint());

String hint = dictionary.get("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a shortcut for filling all the values of a particular row.

```
-> Arrays.fill(Dictionary[i],"value");
```

If you want to fill the whole 2D array.

```
for(String[] array : Dictionary) Arrays.fill(array,"value");
```

By this logic, you can fill any dimension array instead of iterating and assigning each value.